Showcasing PrimeNG Components in Storybook: Anyone Done It? (Style Guide Inspiration)
I'm building a style guide/design system for my Angular project using PrimeNG components. I'd like to leverage Storybook to isolate, document, and showcase these components effectively.
For inspiration, I'm looking to achieve a structure similar to the well-organized Brainly style guide: https://github.com/brainly (https://styleguide.brainly.com/).
Has anyone successfully integrated PrimeNG components within Storybook? Are there any specific configurations needed to ensure proper rendering of the components?
I have not worked with Storybook before, but I got Angular, PrimeNg, and Storybook to work together in one sample project. I was able to create a story file for the button PrimeNG component (button.stories.ts). I am very worried, that I might have to write code in the form of stories instead of just simply importing the PrimeNg controls (and the stories are generated). So that is why I am trying to find out:

What is the best approach to integrate PrimeNg with Storybook?
Are there any specific configurations or workarounds needed to ensure proper rendering of PrimeNG components in Storybook?
Could you point me to any resources or examples showcasing this integration effectively?

Any tips or resources on achieving this setup or overcoming potential challenges would be much appreciated!

You are not using JSF / Faces

PrimeNG (<= 17)
For PrimeNG version 17 and before, do the following:

Create a style sheet (e.g., style.css) with the following content:
@import 'primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css';
@import 'primeng/resources/primeng.css';


Then add this file to the Storybook builder in your angular.json:
"styles": ["[PATH_TO_THE_FILE]/styles.css"],
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": ["node_modules/"]
},



PrimeNG (>= 18)
With PrimeNG version 18 the setup changed completely. You need to inject PrimeNGConfig via Angular's DI as described in the documentation.

Create the preview file in your storybook configuration folder if it doesn't exist yet (.storybook/preview.ts).
In this file, you can add providers that are available in each story. A typical use case, which is also necessary for PrimeNG, is to enable animations here (provideAnimations()). For the PrimeNG setup itself, we can use an
APP_INITIALIZER factory provider that will run during application bootstrap. The dependencies of the provider (PrimeNGConfig) will be injected and passed to the factory function, where we can then set up PrimeNG.

import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { applicationConfig, Preview } from '@storybook/angular';
import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
import { Aura } from 'primeng/themes/aura';

function provideTheme(config: PrimeNGConfig) {
  return () => {
    config.theme.set({
      preset: Aura,
    });
  };
}

const preview: Preview = {
  decorators: [
    applicationConfig({
      providers: [
        provideAnimations(),
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: provideTheme,
          deps: [PrimeNGConfig],
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};

export default preview;


This worked for me, using primen/config and comdoc for documentation.
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { applicationConfig, Preview } from '@storybook/angular';
import { setCompodocJson } from '@storybook/addon-docs/angular';
import docJson from '../documentation.json';

import { PrimeNG } from 'primeng/config';
import Nora from '@primeng/themes/nora';
setCompodocJson(docJson);

function provideTheme(config: PrimeNG) {
  return () => {
    config.theme.set({
      preset: Nora,
      options: {
        darkModeSelector: false,
      },
    });
  };
}

const preview: Preview = {
  decorators: [
    applicationConfig({
      providers: [
        provideAnimations(),
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: provideTheme,
          deps: [PrimeNG],
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};

export default preview;


